# Java program to find perfect numbers below 10,000

Tags: java, perfect-numbers

I am currently working on java code that will allow me to print out all perfect numbers below 10,000.  My issue is that I can not figure out why my code is not printing 6, but is printing all the other perfect numbers.  My code is below, please send help if you can see what I have over looked.  Thank you,

```
int min = 1;
int max = 10000;

for (min = 1; min <= max; min++) {
    int sum = 0;
    int e = 1;
    for (e = 1; e < min; e++) {
        int a = min % e;

        if (a == 0) {
            sum += e;
        }
    } 
    if (sum == min){           
        System.out.println(sum);
    }         
}
```

Comment: The program is printing 6 on my machine

Comment: When I run you code output i get is 6
,28
,496
,8128

Comment: it doesnt gave me any such behaviour as you said http://ideone.com/qTD2c7 .An advice I would give change inner loop condition to `e <= min/2` to make your logic more effiecient

Comment: @singhakash if you are talking about efficiency, you should use square root there...

Comment: Appreciate the fast follow up everyone, I overlooked that my 6 i was looking for was being placed right after an integer that was printed before hand as I did not have my print function move to next line.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution should be fine, but if still has trouble, try to clear then rebuild.

my code listed below gets the correct answers:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int min = 1; 
    int max = 10000;

    for (min = 1; min <= max; min++) { 
        int sum = 0;
        for (int e = 1; e < min; e++) {
            if ((min % e) == 0) {
                sum += e;
            } 
        }  
        if (sum == min){           
            System.out.println(sum);
        }          
    }      
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I am an idiot and my 6 was being "added" to a printed int that was printed before this part of the program.